# Error when qualifying a lead in CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have one user that has problem converting a Lead from an E-Mail.
The error she gets is this one:[image]

Have you ever seen it before?

Comment: Is there any customization on Lead form? Any javascript?

Comment: Yes. But other users don't have this problem. I added the organisation in my Outlook and I could perform the operation without any error

Comment: hmm! I don't think its a browser issue because its throwing null reference exception. But if other users are able to convert emails to leads with same info, I would suggest you to check your browser version. Try in compatibility mode.

Answer (score 0):

There must be a permission issue due to which the CRM is unable to retrieve data.
Check the Append Permission or read permission of the records which is used in the email. Most Probably it must be from user contact, or account